# Active Sync Deleted All My Contacts!

Tags: microsoft-outlook, windows-mobile, activesync

I have a mobile with Windows Mobile 6 that I synchronize using Windows 7 using Windows Mobile Device Center. I also use "My Phone" service to back up my important data, especially my contacts and messages.

I connected my mobile to a PC with Windows XP, Outlook and Active Sync installed to use the internet from tha PC. Although I tried to make sure to uncheck all the synchronization option, Active Sync found its way to ruin my day... it deletes all my contacts from the mobile because it synchronized it with Outlook contacts on the PC, which was empty. Or was it because I deleted a previous "Partnership" (I used to sync with my Windows XP laptop)?

I have my back up in two places (I hope), Windows Mobile Device Center and "My Phone" service, but I'm afraid that if I connected my mobile to my Windows 7 PC it will automatically deletes the contacts from the PC to be in "sync" with the phone. The same is also applicable on "My Phone" service.

I couldn't find an option in both that tells the synchronization process to overwrite the mobile data instead.

The question is how can I get my contacts back?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Phone doesn't delete items that are deleted from your phone. It archives them instead. If you go to the [My Phone website](http://sn1-p1.myphone.microsoft.com/), you'll see that your contacts are still there. All you have to do is sync your phone and it should restore your contacts.